# Pass Image ID to URL segment

Tags: php, jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-3

I am trying to click the next button on an image to load the next image from the results fetched from the database, but load a new page so the bootstrap carousel is not working as I need it to.

Let's say I have an album with 3 images. The image id's for these images are - 25, 34, 36. When I am viewing the album with all images I can click on Image ID 34. This will take me to www.domain.com/image/34 when I click next I want to redirect to www.domain.com/image/36 and then click next again would redirect to www.domain.com/image/25

So here is what I have so far:

Controller:

```
function index($image_id)
{
    // get album data                       
    $this->data['image_data'] = $this->album_model->get_album_image_data($image_id);

    $album_id = $this->data['image_data']->album_id;
    $this->data['album_images']  = $this->album_model->get_all_images($album_id);

    $data = $this->data;           

    $this->_render_page('images/image', $data);
}
```

View:

```
foreach($album_images as $img)
{
    if($img->image_id == $this->uri->segment(2))
    {
        echo '<img src="'.$img->image_url.'" class="img-responsive img-panel" class="img-responsive" />';
    }  
}
<!-- Image nav -->
<a class="fui-arrow-left left" href="#"></a>
<a class="fui-arrow-right right" href="#"></a>
```

How do I get the next and previous image_id?

Please let me know if I need to include more info.

Comment: Like if Id is 24 than get next id as `SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID > 24 LIMIT 1` ... Than ID > 34 ... So on

Comment: get all your id's and store them in an array -- then its just a case of using the index id to retrieve the data and do whatever -- +1 for next or -1 for previous  -- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Comment: doesn't the foreach already give out array? should I take `$img->image_id` and store them in another array?

Comment: well this look like the array ($album_images) but im not sure what kind of an array it is -- regardless of what you still go by the index position id to retrieve the data. i think its better if you use ajax to retrieve the data and create the array using Jquery. You may need to resort in using cookies for the next or previous id if you go the php way

Comment: @Tasos I have never done that before. If you can give an example that would be great.

Comment: @devpro wouldn't that just get the next ID greater than 24? The database could have Image Id's 24,25,26,etc but only 25,34,36 belong to the album images I am viewing.

Comment: Than u must have a specific value for getting 24,34,36 use this. With > ID

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/json-data-jquery-php-mysql/  -- using the $.getJSON  (an ajax premade function) will fetch the data and put in an array

Comment: You need to provide markup as meant in [bootstrap carousel](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp). You can see that you need wrapper (e.g. `class="carousel-inner"`) where you put your images for carousel could work.

Comment: @Tpojka i don't want to use the bootstrap carousel. I need a new page to load with the next image id in the album

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pagination, first load the pagination library .`$this->load->library('pagination');`
refer https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html?highlight=pagination

**controller**

```
public function index()
{
   $config['base_url'] = site_url('dashboard-clients');
   $config['total_rows'] = //total count of your image or data
   $config['per_page'] = 1;

  //show the number of pages
  $choice = $config['total_rows']/$config['per_page'];
  $config['num_link'] = round($choice);
  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) :0;
  $result = $this->Your_Model->get('table name',$config['per_page'], $page)
  $str_links = $this->pagination->cretae_links();
  $data['links'] = explode('&nbsp', $str_links);
  if($result != FALSE)
  {
    $data['data'] = $result;
    $this->load->view('yoyr view file', $data);
  }
}
```

**model**

```
public function get($table, $limit, $start)
{
  $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
  $query = $this->db->get($table);
  if($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
    return $query->reult();
  }
  else
    return FALSE;
}
```

**view**

```
foreach($data as $img)
{
     echo '<img src="'.$img->image_url.'" class="img-responsive img-panel" class="img-responsive" />'; 
}
//create links like 1 ,2, 3,next
<div id="pagination" align="center">
     <ul class="pagination">
         <?php if (isset($links) and is_array($links)) {
              foreach ($links as $link) {
                  echo '<li>'.$link.'</li>';
               }
           }?>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the suggestions, but I actually found an easier and cleaner way to do it.

I found this [function](https://github.com/phacility/libphutil/blob/master/src/utils/utils.php#L198) that I created an array helper with and it helped me store the image id's in an array.

Once I was able to store my id's in an array as I needed them, I added this to my view:

```
$index = array_search($this->uri->segment(2), $image_ids);                        
$next = (count($image_ids) == $index+1) ? $image_ids[0] : $image_ids[$index+1];                        
$prev = ($index == 0) ? $image_ids[count($image_ids)-1] : $image_ids[$index-1]; 

<a class="fui-arrow-left left" href="<?=$prev?>"></a>
<a class="fui-arrow-right right" href="<?=$next?>"></a>
```